# TypeScript doesn't work nicely with the reduce array helper

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have these types defined with the API

```
interface Role {
  Path: pathType;
  RoleName: roleNameType;
  RoleId: idType;
  Tags?: tagListType;
}

type roleListType = Role[];

export interface ListRolesResponse {
  Roles: roleListType;
}
```

And I am trying to get the roles from this API calls

```
const response = await api.listRoles().promise();
```

and here TS can infer the type of `response` correctly, which is `response: PromiseResult<ListRolesResponse, Error>`

And this response can be an array looking like this

```
[
  ({
    Path: "/service-role/",
    RoleId: "3434343",
    RoleName: "myRole1",
    Tags: "tag1",
  },
  {
    Path: "/service-role/",
    RoleId: "45454545",
    RoleName: "myRole2",
    Tags: "tag2",
  },
  {
    Path: "/service-role/",
    RoleId: "124543543",
    RoleName: "myRole3",
    Tags: "tag1",
  }),
];
```

And my goal is to get an array of role name for the roles that have `tag1` as its tag.
`['myRole1', myRole3]`, and I defined a type for it

```
type RoleNames = string[]
```

I decided to go with `reduce` to process the list of roles and this is where things get tricky, so when I typed out the `reduce` helper method, it seemed like the type inference was gone. To be specific, here `curr` is not inferred as `Role`, when in fact it is of the type of `Role`

```
response.Roles.reduce((curr, prev) => {
    //..
 }, [])
```

I noticed that if I switch to using the `map` helper method, the type inference can be preserved. i.e. `role` is still inferred correctly as `Role`

```
response.Roles.map(role => ...)
```

I am curious about why there is this difference.

And ultimately I want to do something like this

```
response.Roles.reduce((curr: Role, prev: RoleNames) => {
    if(curr.Tags.includes('tag1')) return prev.concat(curr.RoleName)
    return prev
 }, [] as RoleNames)
```

However the TS compiler is still yelling at me, saying `No overload matches this call.` The error message is too long and this is the screenshot of part of it.

I wonder how I can properly type my reduce function here?

[image]

Comment: The response does not look normal. Why the objects inside the array is wrapped inside `()`

Comment: the response with wrong format can't use standard function `( )`

Answer (score 0):

`reduce` has the signature

```
arr.reduce(callback( accumulator, currentValue, [, index[, array]] )[, initialValue])
```

So the code should be

```
response.Roles.reduce((prev, curr) => { // not (curr, prev)
    //..
 }, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are switching the `reduce` callback arguments order. The first argument is the accumulated value, in your case the array you want to build. The second argument is the current item from the original list.

```
arr.reduce((accumulated: RoleNames, curr: Role) => {
    // execute your logic
    return accumulated
}, [] as RoleNames)
```